# Navigate to anchor, preserve queryparams and dont reload page

Tags: angular, angular11

My current url is: **/home/project?id=3** and I want to go to **/home/project?id=3#anchorTest** without reloading the page. So basically I'd like to scroll down to the anchor. How to best do this?

```
  public gotoAnchor(anchorName: string): void {
    this.router.navigate([this.router.url], {fragment: anchorName}); // Goes all wrong regarding the queryparams
  }
```

Also fails:

```
<a [routerLink]="<What to use here to preserve the queryparams?>" fragment="anchorTest">Goto test</a>
```

Also, when I click it again I don't want this url but just a single anchor of course: **/home/project?id=3#anchorTest#anchorTest**

This gives a 404:

```
  public gotoAnchor(anchorName: string): void {
    this.router.navigate([this.router.url], {fragment: anchorName, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'}); // Error 404: /home/project%3Fid%3D2?id=3#anchorTest
  }
```

This works only once (because the url is the same when calling this a second time)

```
this.router.navigate([this.router.url.split('?')[0]], {fragment: anchorName, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found another way to make it work w/o reloading or messing around with parameters.

Html:

```
<h1 id="top">Title - Foo</h1> <!-- Scroll to this element -->
<!-- Other code here -->
<li><a role="button" (click)="navClick('top')">Top</a></li>
```

Typescript:

```
  public navClick(elementId: string): void {
    document.getElementById(elementId)?.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
  }
```

Comment: since you are using Angular, you might not want to use document.getElementById.
Angular apps might not always run in a browser, Angular it's designed to run on multiple platforms (e.g. web workers / server side). I would rather use elementRef or viewChild (my favorite).

Answer (score 0):

try the QueryParamsHandling -merge-
[angular docu](https://angular.io/api/router/QueryParamsHandling)

Comment: Now the anchor is correct but the url is still error 404: /home/project%3Fid%3D2?id=3#anchorTest
I also tried encodeURIComponent(this.router.url) but the same issue, why is the url wrong? I think I have to strip the parameters out of the this.router.url? Isn't there a better solution than having to replace the characters manually?

Comment: it seems you are mixing url with params here...have a look at your code, the '%3Fid%3D2' is the encoding for '?id=' which is not part of the url

Comment: this.router.navigate([this.router.url.split('?')[0]], {fragment: anchorName, queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'});

I see. The above line works but only once. If the user scrolls down and then uses the anchor again, Angular does nothing because the url is already the same.